# How to apply horizontal and vertical "translation" by ∆x and ∆y pixels to each frame of a video using ffmpeg or other tool

Tags: ffmpeg, video, translation, frame, transform

I have a video of a subject that needs to be tracked by an image tracking software. The problem is, at some point in the video, the camera has been moved, so the area of tracking "shifts" at a certain timestamp in the video. So, I need to cut the "shifted" part and separate it from the correct part, and hopefully, apply a "translation" transformation to the frames by a certain number of pixels in the x and y directions, and then concat the two parts back to each other. I know how to cut and concat videos, but I do not know how to apply the "translation" transformation to the shifted part.

Is that possible with ffmpeg? If yes, how can I do that. If not, then can anyone suggest a preferably free tool that does that?

I sifted through ffmpeg's documentation, and this seems to be promising:
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#remap_005fopencl
But I cannot figure out how to actually use it.

Any and all help is appreciated.

EDIT 1:
The reason I am involving the reader with the complication of cutting and concating the pieces, even though I know how to do those things is, that, tracking software have the option to define "where" the subject to be tracked is in the video frame, but I wanted to clarify that shifting the "tracking area" in the tracking software is not an option, because the tracking area moves at some point in the video, due to the camera movement.

Comment: *So, I need to cut the "shifted" part* --> Do you need to cut or correct the shifted part?

Comment: What I meant was, cut the shifted part, transform the shifted part, and then concat the corrected part back with the other piece.

Comment: @Gyan I updated the question to clarify what I need. The reason I involved the reader with the complication of cutting and concating the pieces, even though I knew how to do those things was, that, tracking software have the option to define "where" the subject to be tracked is in the video frame, but I wanted to clarify that shifting the "tracking area" in the tracking software is not an option, because the tracking area moves at some point in the video, due to the camera movement.